# How to use dd to make splitted ISO images from an storage device?

Tags: ssh, dd, reference-book

This is a *double question*, I just hope it's valid.

- I need to know how to use [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)) to make splitted ISO images from some storage device, I'm doing it through SSH: **the process is slow and the risk of faling at the mid of the operation** (**1**) is high then I need to know how to make these splitted ISO images from my storage device (**2**) and also how to merge all the pieces after the process.
- I'm searching for some reference on [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_(Unix)), it could be a book or a good website about it for when any doubt arises.

**1** - I'm doing it on a ~60GB storage device, it took me a whole day to copy ~10GB from this disk.

**2** - For curious people, I'm trying to recover an accidentaly deleted file from an iPod, until now I've been able to make the whole process, I just need to improve it beucase I left it copying the disk yesterday: Today it gave me an error when it was at ~10GB.

Comment: on DD
Please Reffer the below question that will well answer your question also
http://superuser.com/questions/407324/why-does-dd-not-work-for-creating-bootable-usb

Comment: Why are you doing this over ssh?

Comment: @Paul The guides I've found used SSH, I imagined that it could be faster through FTP, but I don't know how to do it via FTP.

Comment: I mean why can't you just plug the ipod into your local machine so you don't need to use the network at all.

Comment: @Paul It's impossible, it's a iPod touch (3rd generation), it's impossible to do the way you suggested - I've searched for it and this was the only way I've found.

Comment: Please can you [edit] the question and describe in more detail what you are doing.  I don't doubt it is "impossible" but that is not enough information to help.

Comment: @Paul More detail about what?

Comment: From the description it isn't possible to understand why ssh is involved, where the ipod is connected etc.

Comment: I've elaborated a [better question here.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/222714/is-it-possible-to-use-dd-to-obtain-splited-images-from-a-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0):

[ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) to rescue!

You need just two things:

1. use it with logfile to continue if the dd is interrupted
2. there is an option to do the quick rescue first (and skip any failing blocks) and try harder to recover those

It could work over ssh using sshfs - but that may be rather slow.