# how to boot debian from partition?

Tags: boot, debian, iso-image

I have downloaded debian iso in sub, then did

```
$ sudo dd bs=4M if=/Downloads/firmware-10.4.0-i386-DVD-1.iso of=/dev/sdb status=progress && sync
```

But the iso has saved in partition, instead of device itself:
$lsblk:

```
sdb      8:16   1  14.4G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   3.7G  0 part /media/user/Debian 10.4.0 i386 1
└─sdb2   8:18   1   2.2M  0 part
```

And from here [Why does 'dd' not work for creating bootable USB?](https://superuser.com/questions/407324/why-does-dd-not-work-for-creating-bootable-usb/407327#407327) is mentioned, i cannot boot from partition. But from the command above, as seen, I have specified device /dev/sdb and not partition /dev/sdb*, so should I now try to dd again? or *is here possibility to boot from partition?* But in boot menu in start, there is only to boot from other devices such as /dev/sdc and I do do not see possibility to boot from /dev/sdb1 which now contains the iso, so how to boot the iso and installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the output of `lsblk`.

The file you've downloaded and written is a disk image containing two partitions. By writing the image to disk, you've created a partition table with these partitions. (That's also the reason why writing to a partition doesn't work: partitions can't be nested.) This is the intended result.

Now I don't know what "boot menu" you're looking at, but apparently it's using Linux naming conventions (`/dev/sdc` etc.), so I'm guessing it's GRUB. That's already too late, your UEFI (motherboard's firmware, also incorrectly called BIOS - these are not used anymore) uses GRUB as its default bootloader. You have to interrupt the normal boot and select partition there. This is usually done by pressing some button during boot. You could also press `c` in GRUB, enter `fwsetup` command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> - this should take you to UEFI setup which will let you reorder bootloaders.

Comment: Maybe his _i386_ based computer, even today, still uses a BIOS?? Haven't seen one with a UEFI firmware. ;-)

Comment: The problem is from UEFI setup (called "InsydeH20 setup utility"), in boot section, there are only option to change boot mode and secure boot, no option to change or select bootloader (There is also boot priority - I have windows before), but do not know how to select iso from the usb. Any idea?

Comment: I needed to switch from UEFI to legacy : https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/110162/Add+Boot+Option+using+Insydeh20+setup+utility, but is seems hacky for me